# How to get div to align and stay put?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

When I toggle the menu icon on my nav bar in mobile view, I can't get the 'work' and 'contact' links to align under the name and stay put. I'm targeting the .topnav.responsive #nav-bar ul in media queries which seems to be moving it, but can't figure out what properties to use to make it align under the 'name' when the menu icon is toggled on.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  line-height: 19px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

ul {
  margin:0;
  padding-top: -80;
}

#nav-bar {
    float: right;
}

.nav-link a {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

#nav-bar li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    line-height: 80px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

#work {
  margin-right: -5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #nav-bar ul {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: -2px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: fixed;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 20px;
  }
  .topnav.responsive #nav-bar ul {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    right: 300px;
    top: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  .topnav a {
    padding:20px;
  }
  
  #nav-bar li {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">    

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="home.html" class="active">NAME</a>
  <div id="nav-bar">
                <ul>
                    <li style="list-style-type: none;" class="nav-link"><a id="work" href="#">WORK</a></li>
                    <li style="list-style-type: none;" class="nav-link"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use floats they're just a bit difficult to control, use flex instead.

I've made a few changes removed some unnecessary code to keep it simple and understandable.

I won't explain what every property is doing that'll take all night, i'm pretty sure you're familiar with most, However if you have any questions please do ask.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
  display: flex;
}

.topnav a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  line-height: 19px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .topnav>ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .topnav.responsive>ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .topnav a {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="home.html" class="active">NAME</a>

  <ul>
    <li style="list-style-type: none;" class="nav-link"><a id="work" href="#">WORK</a></li>
    <li style="list-style-type: none;" class="nav-link"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: great that worked perfectly, thank you so much! I've familiar with everything on there except the * at the start of the CSS. I've seen it before, but I'm not exactly sure what it's targeting?

Comment: `*` is a wild card it selects everything in the page `*:before' selects the pseudo-elements of all elements which is not needed for this to work, it's mostly used to reset padding and margins on all elements without having to go through each and every element alone and also setting box-sizing to border-box for the elements to include padding and border width within theirs width